# ОШИБКА:System::Drawing::Graphics::Graphics нет подходящего конструктора по умолчанию

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

В моей программе в конструкторе я выделил память под Graphics с помощью gcnew,и в результате компилятор выдал ошибку.Если не выделять под него то будет другая ошибка "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр класса".Как быть в этом случае?Я понимаю что можно в обработчике события написать e->Graphics->DrawPolygon,но мне надо это сделать в созданной мной функции так как хочу сделать фрактал треугольник Серпинского то есть вызывать в рекурсивной функции Graphics->DrawPolygon(..)
код:

```
#pragma once

namespace Project1 {

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;


    /// <summary>
    /// Сводка для MyForm
    /// </summary>
    public ref class MyForm : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:


        MyForm(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //
            //TODO: добавьте код конструктора
            //
            aPen = gcnew System::Drawing::Pen(Color::Black, 1);
            Графика = gcnew Graphics;



        }
    private:
        System::Drawing::Pen^ aPen; // карандаш
        Graphics^Графика;
        array<PointF>^P;
    protected:
        /// <summary>
        /// Освободить все используемые ресурсы.
        /// </summary>
        ~MyForm()
        {
            if (components)
            {
                delete components;
            }
        }

    private:
        /// <summary>
        /// Обязательная переменная конструктора.
        /// </summary>
        System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
        /// <summary>
        /// Требуемый метод для поддержки конструктора — не изменяйте 
        /// содержимое этого метода с помощью редактора кода.
        /// </summary>
        void InitializeComponent(void)
        {
            this->SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // MyForm
            // 
            this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
            this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
            this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(518, 347);
            this->Name = L"MyForm";
            this->Text = L"MyForm";
            this->Load += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MyForm::MyForm_Load);
            this->Paint += gcnew System::Windows::Forms::PaintEventHandler(this, &MyForm::MyForm_Paint);
            this->ResumeLayout(false);

        }
#pragma endregion

        void draw(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2, double x3, double y3, double n) {
            P = gcnew array<PointF>(3);
            double x1n, y1n, x2n, y2n, x3n, y3n;

            if (n > 0) {

            x1n = (x1 + x2) / 2;
            y1n = (y1 + y2) / 2;
            x2n = (x2 + x3) / 2;
            y2n = (y2 + y3) / 2;
            x3n = (x3 + x1) / 2;
            y3n = (y3 + y1) / 2;
                draw(x1, y1, x1n, y1n, x3n, y3n, n - 1);
                draw(x2, y2, x1n, y1n, x2n, y2n, n - 1);
                draw(x3, y3, x2n, y2n, x3n, y3n, n - 1);
                P[0].X = x1n;
                P[0].Y = y1n;
                P[1].X = x2n;
                P[1].Y = y2n;
                P[2].X = x3n;
                P[2].Y = y3n;
                Графика->DrawPolygon(aPen, P);
            }
        }
    private: System::Void MyForm_Paint(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::PaintEventArgs^  e) {

        int x1 = 320;
        int x2 = 600;
        int x3 = 40;
        int y1 = 10;
        int y2 = 470;
        int y3 = 470;
        int n = 5;
        draw(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, n);




    }
```